# Change .NET Thread UI Culture from Win32

Tags: .net, winapi, localization, com

I have an application that is part MFC, part ATL, and part .NET--base part is MFC but there are several hundred libraries.

Entry to .NET is through exposing COM interfaces...somewhere MFC calls COM and a .NET object is created. There are many possible paths and sometimes nothing in .NET might be called.

What I am interested in doing is testing our localization in a different language on a local machine that is probably English (en-US). For the MFC stuff, I can call `SetProcessPreferredUILanguage()` or `SetThreadPreferredUILanguage()` and the logic of the program picks it up. Inside any individual .NET component I can call Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture and set it to a culture.

However, since I can enter into .NET at many, many different entry points, I just would like to make a call into a Windows API function somewhere, and then when a .NET object is created and the .NET runtime is initialized, I'd like the .NET runtime to pick it up.  I've tried `SetProcessPreferredUILanguage()`, `SetThreadPreferredUILanguage()`, and `SetThreadUILanguage()` without any luck. They change behavior on the Win32 side, but not on the .NET side.  I could make some .NET COM object especially just for setting the UI culture, but I'd prefer not to do that. I'd rather not go through the overhead of spinning up the .NET runtime until I need it, if I need it.

Is there a way from the Windows API side to effect the UI culture of the .NET runtime executing in my application?

Comment: Why don't you add a method in your .NET objects that would set the current culture?

Comment: There are hundreds. There are probably a dozen or two base classes. I want the C++ side to control the UI language. I could create a simple object to call from COM to set the UI language/culture, but I don't always use the .NET objects. Sometimes it is just regular C++ and I don't want to spin up the .NET if I don't have to. I would rather just find a way to make an API call that when .NET spins up, it will change the UI Culture.

Comment: With .NET 4.5 and higher, you just have to call `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` once: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture.aspx or if for testing purposes, change the user's regional settings and restart app (which IMHO does an even better test)